# How to incorporate lxml (Python) to CGI file

Tags: python, cgi, lxml

I have written python code to get a url,read its source, and get the title of the website. I'm trying to put that into a CGI file, and have that file return the title name via HTML.

How would the CGI file implementing this look like? How would you implement the imports of this file? How can I have the file return HTML?

Comment: Easiest is to use something like Flask or Bottle

Comment: @pvg Thank you for the response, but I want to do it in CGI if I can

Comment: Use the cgi module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html